# ''Der zug fährt 9 uhr ab'' why ''fährt'' is used in this context?

Tags: conjugation

> Der zug fährt 9 uhr ab'

Why is *fährt* (presence/Präsens) used in this case?

In this case of separable verb 'abfahren' how do I tell which form of fahren to use?

with reference to this list
http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-abfahren.html

Comment: You should pay attention to capitalisation of substantives in German. This is not just a "nice to have". It is obligatory.

Comment: To close voters: the reason *no replacement of conjugation table etc.* does not fit, because apparently the main point that confuses the OP is the fact that something to happen in future is expressed using present and not futur1.

Comment: I would be surprised if there were no existing question that concerned the use of present to represent future events.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  It would be interesting to hear what Yozansen's usual everyday language is. Most languages I know know the concept of using present tense for certain things thought to be happening in the future.

Comment: @Jan Closing as duplikat would be something different, I just said that the given reason (sub-category of off-topic) does not fit.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Correct, I wasn’t referring to your comment specifically but just pointing out my general thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By

1. observing that the statement is simply descriptive, so the finite verb is in indicative mood;
2. observing that the subject of the sentence is *der Zug*, so the finite verb is a 3rd person singular ("er/sie/es");
3. observing that it is an active statement (the subject, ie the train, does something), so the finite verb is an active voice;
4. observing that the statement refers to a planned future action and that, in German, such statements are expressed either in Futur I or present tense and that, in cases where the context specifies a point in time for the event to very likely occur, present tense is strongly prefered;
5. combining your insights from (1) through (4) and locating the appropriate form in the table: *er/sie/es fährt ab*.

As a side note, it's usually *Der Zug fährt **um** 9/10/11 [Uhr] ab*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the time, the sentence is "Der Zug fährt ab." The time written on the table is relevant. Therefore the time is presence. Further details become included.

> "Der Zug fährt 9h ab."
>   "Der Zug fährt Dienstag um 9h ab."
>   ...

If you would say:

> "Der Zug wird 9h abfahren."

you would be absoltly convinced the physical train starts 9h moving.